# GNU Objective-C Makefile

Tags: objective-c, c, makefile

I am trying to compile some Objective-C code that requires the `Foundation/Foundation.h` header. Currently that isn't included in GCC's path so I need to add a bunch of compiler flags in order for it to properly build. I can do this manually with ease but cannot figure out how to do this using a `Makefile`. The contents of my current file are as follows.

```
#Compiler flags
CFLAGS=-I. -I/home/benjamin/GNUstep/Library/Headers -I/usr/local/include/GNUstep -I/usr/include/GNUstep

#Compiles all of the .o files after generation
all: foo.o baz.o
        gcc foo.o baz.o -o FooBarBaz -lobjc
#Steps to compile foo.o
foo.o:foo.m bar.h
        gcc -c foo.m
#Steps to compile baz.o
baz.o:baz.m bar.h
        gcc -c baz.m
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you have assigned a variable `CFLAGS`, but then you didn't use the variable in your recipes anywhere.

Comment: How do I use the variable? It was my understanding that it automatically used it with every step in the build process.

Comment: And... I guess I missed that entire part of the Makefile tutorial. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: Please see/use gnustep-make package.